# dynamic dispatch in c from scala

Tags: c, scala, dispatch

I am trying to implement dynamic dispatch in C, translating from scala. as part of my code in C I have

```
typedef struct File{
  void (**vtable)();
  char *node;
  int *size;
}File;

//function
Node  *newFile(char *n, int *s);

int *newFile_Size(Node* n){
  return (int *)n->size;
}

void (*Folder_Vtable[])() = {(VF) &newFile_Size};

Node  *newFile(char *n, int *s){
  File *temp = NEW(File);
  temp->vtable= Folder_Vtable;
  temp->node=n;
  temp->size=s;
  return (Node *) temp;
}
```

which is the translation of below code in scala:

```
class File(n: String, s: Int) extends Node(n) {
  var size: Int = s
}
```

when I compile my C code I get this error:

```
./solution.c:123:30: note: passing argument to parameter 's' here
Node  *newFile(char *n, int *s){
```

This is how the function is called:

```
Node* file = newFile("file_to_test", 1);
```

and I get this warning/error like 5 times. Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Is your error statement complete ? It seems that it is not described entirely...

Comment: (int *)n->size; you seem to be casting n to a pointer to an int and not the result, try  int *k = (n->size) , and then return k.

Comment: @tesseract I dont thi k so since the error comes from the parameter S.

Comment: @Coconop what do you mean???

Comment: I mean that usually you have something like: `passing argument makes pointer from integer without a cast` or `passing argument discards qualifiers from pointer target type` etc...

Comment: What does the solution.c line 123 look like? Can you update your question to include it?

Comment: @Coconop well its says ./solution.c:123:30: note: passing argument to parameter 's' here
Node  *newFile(char *n, int *s){, I dont really get what is the problem here.

Comment: @leeduhem I just updated the question, its basially thi Node  *newFile(char *n, int *s){

Comment: @S.N Well, that is strange. If it is possible, please post the whole `solution.c`.

Comment: @ its not possible its a part of my assignment and i am not suppose to o that, and its a long code.

Comment: I think the issue is in the code that **calls** `newFile()`: can you add it in your question ?

Comment: And I still think the warning error is not quoted entirely: don't you have a statement beginning with ''warning'' or ''error'' before the ''note''?

Comment: @Coconop here is the complete C code: http://pastebin.com/QbginRSF

Comment: and here is the one in scala: pastebin.com/R79DJE4d.

Comment: Actually I really meant about the file that calls the function, probably your `main()` : do you have any ?

Comment: @Coconop here you go: http://pastebin.com/3WJRuHnj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here is the issue:

In your main:

```
Node* file1 = newFile("file_to_test", 1);
```

`newFile()` is expecting a reference on integer but you are passing an integer directly.

You should try something like:

```
int size = 1;
Node* file1 = newFile("file_to_test", &size);
```

Or (if you don't want to modify your main):

```
typedef struct File{
  void (**vtable)();
  char *node;
  int size;
}File;
//function
Node  *newFile(char *n, int s);
// Update other functions
```

Comment: cant do this. I am not suppose to change the main.

Comment: Then `newFile()` should take an `int` rather than an `int*` in parameter: update your functions/structure in consequence.

Comment: We shouldn't overload this discussion with a new topic... Please accept the answer if it does solve your initial issue so we can end this discussion, then make a new question for your new problem.
Don't forget to include all the elements required for a clear understanding ;)

Comment: can you take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22114217/translating-a-scala-code-into-c-using-vtm