# Dynamic dispatch, C

Tags: c, scala, dispatch

I am using the following scala code trying to translate this code into C using virtual method tables(dynamic dispatch).

this is the code in scala:

```
abstract class Node(n: String) {
  val id = Node.next
  var name: String = n
  def size: Int
  def nrNodes: Int = 1
  def find(q: String): Set[Node] = 
    if(name.contains(q)) Set(this) else Set()
}
```

My problem is with this part of the code:

```
def find(q: String): Set[Node] = 
        if(name.contains(q)) Set(this) else Set()
```

I am trying to translate it into C, and this is what I have so far:

```
Set find(Node *n, char * s){
 if(strstr(s,n->name)!=0){
   return (Set) n->name;
 }
 return ((Set (*)(Node *))  n->vtable[FIND])(n);
}
```

So find returns a set of nodes if it contains a Node else an empty set. when I run this it gives the following error:

```
error: unknown type name 'Set' 
use of undeclared identifier 'Set'
```

I am not sure if I have to use struct Set or my find method is wrong in general!

Here is my vtable:

```
enum Node_vtablekeys{
  SIZE=0,
  NRNODERS=1,
  FIND=2
};
```

Comment: Have you actually declared `Set` anywhere?

Comment: @rightfold Do you mean like in typedef of node?? I should put struct Set set?

Comment: If `set` is a struct, its type name is `struct set` unless you have used `typedef` to create a nickname for that type. And don't forget that you have to actually design and declare that `struct`!

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments it seems that you forgot to declare your structure:

```
typedef struct _set
{
    // Whatever Set must contains
} Set;
```

Moreover, I don't really know Scala but in `find()` it looks like if you don't find a match, the function actually creates a new `Set` so I guess there should be a `malloc` in your function.
Can you show us the scala Set structure ?

Depending of how you use `find()` it might be more useful to return a reference rather than the  `Set` structure itself.

```
Set * find(Node *n, char * s)
{
    if(strstr(s,n->name)!=0)
    {
       return (Set) &(n->name);
    }
    else
    {
        Set * new_set = malloc(sizof(Set));
        // Copy attributes from n->vtable[FIND])(n) to new_set
        return new_set; 
    }
}
```